# AssetConversionApi (asset_conversion_pallet) - How to encode function input parameters in price and reserves RPC calls?

Tags: pallet, rpc, assets, json-rpc, westend

I'm trying to use asset_conversion pallet to call quote prices, and get reserved rpc endpoints (defined [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L2377))

In pallets official docs there is small [section](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_asset_conversion/index.html) about calling that endpoint, but it doesn't specify how to encode input parameters. So I wanted to check if anyone know how to encode them (preferably in js/ts)

Note: There is also this [file](https://hackmd.io/@sn8Hc8CXRsmGb7q0kYzxHw/r190_X_m2), explaining get reserves call, but still nothing about encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install polkadot/api and use api.createType and u8aToHex to encode the parameters
Code Example:

#### Installation:

`yarn add @polkadot/api`

#### Usage

```
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';
import { u8aToHex } from '@polkadot/util';

const main = async () => {
    const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://westend-asset-hub-rpc.polkadot.io');
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
    await api.isReady; 

    // get input parameters as encoded SCALE Uint8Array
    // asset in asset hub with id 1
    const multiLocation = api.createType('MultiLocation', {
        parent: 0,
        interior: {
          X2: [
            { PalletInstance: 50 },
            { GeneralIndex: 4200 }
          ]
        }
    }).toU8a();
    const multiLocation2 = api.createType('MultiLocation', {
      parent: 0,
      interior: {
        here: null
      }
    }).toU8a();
    const amount = api.createType('u128', 2).toU8a();
    const bool = api.createType('bool', false).toU8a();
   
    // concatenate  Uint8Arrays of input parameters 
    const encodedInput = new Uint8Array(multiLocation.length + multiLocation2.length);
    encodedInput.set(multiLocation, 0); // Set array1 starting from index 0
    encodedInput.set(multiLocation2, multiLocation.length); // Set array2 starting from the end of array1
    encodedInput.set(amount, multiLocation.length + multiLocation2.length); // Set array3 starting from the end of array1 + array2
    encodedInput.set(bool, multiLocation.length + multiLocation2.length + amount.length); // Set array3 starting from the end of array1 + array2
    
    // create Hex from concatenated u8a
    const encodedInputHex = u8aToHex(encodedInput);
    
    // call rpc state call where first parameter is method to be called and second one is Hex representation of encoded input parameters
    const response = await api.rpc.state.call('AssetConversionApi_quote_price_exact_tokens_for_tokens', encodedInputHex)    

    // decode response
    const decodedprice = api.createType('Option<u128>', response);
    console.log(decodedprice.toHuman());
};
main();
```